# Facebook login do not work on some devices

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

My problem is the following: I notice that some users trying to login in my app fail to login. It happens to maybe 20% of them and I am not sure which phone they use. I notice the observation on iPhone and android phones.

I believe this is maybe due to one of my parameter in the facebook console, but I am not sure which one.
[image]

[image]

Did anyone of you entered in that scenario before?
At the moment I can see the API stat from facebook that see errors when users try to login but I do not know how to get the error information

[image]

At the moment it looks like those users always end up in the error case of the facebook API when logging in.

Objective C code:

```
if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil)
        [self loginUser];
    else{
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;

        // THIS PART ALWAYS SWAP FROM MY APP TO FACEBOOK APP
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[FACEBOOK_EMAIL, FACEBOOK_PUBLICPROFILE] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                if (error){
                    [login logOut];
                }
                else if ([result isCancelled] == YES){
                    [login logOut];
                }
                else{
                    [self loginUser];
                }
            }];

    }
```

Android code:

```
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            // Register the callback manager to the facebook login manager
            loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                // If the callback is sucessfull then we log the user in
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    logUserIntoApp();
                }

                @Override
                // If the callback specify that the user cancel the facebook login
                public void onCancel() {
                    Mint.logExceptionMessage("onCancelFacebookLogin", null, new Exception("onCancelFacebookLogin"));
                    setFinResult(CANCEL);
                }

                @Override
                // If there was an error, we specify that there was an error during the facebook login
                public void onError(FacebookException exception){
                    Mint.logExceptionMessage("onErrorFacebookLogin", null, new Exception("onErrorFacebookLogin"));
                    setFinResult(FAIL);
                }
            });
            // First check if the user is already logged in, and if he is then logged in automatically in TMO
            if (isLogedIn()) logUserIntoApp();
                // Otherwise login the user with the required permissions
            else loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "user_birthday", "public_profile"));
```

Here are the store links too:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.appus.takemeout
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tmo-dating/id1032349052?mt=8

Any help on this would be very appreciated. thanks

Comment: Does it throw an exception when the Facebook app is installed ? Uninstalled ? Opened ? The user is already connected ?

Comment: And what is 'nil' on the first line ? It should not be 'null' ? :)

Comment: @Alexandre Martin: I cannot reproduce on any of my phone this is the issue. I tried with facebook app installed, desinstalled etc... I have an iphone 5, nexus 4 and a galaxy S6 all of them worked properly. Also my friend around me have no issues. But I know some users do based on logs and feedback I got on social medias. For the nil, this is the same thing as null in objective C. I can change this but I do not think the issue is coming from there.

Comment: Can you test it on emulated devices on Android Studio ? I am not sure if the Login Manager can be tested this way...

Comment: Android studio worked too :( I really do not know how to reproduce the issue

Comment: Ok so what is the exact error message you got ?

Comment: And again, what is the 'nil' standing for on the first line? Maybe you missed my second comment :)

Comment: Basically when the user press the login button. It does nothing at all. The user press it about 10 times and see nothing going on  (this is what happens on phone where it does not work). If I use my phones the issue is not there and I can login without issues. The cide above is objectice C. Let me update with the android one as well

Comment: Does your key hash is entered properly ?

Comment: And your Facebook Api does not give more informations about the error ?

Comment: I would think so otherwise why would some user be able to login and others not? Also the key hash would only impact android users I guess but not iphone one?

Comment: And your Facebook Api does not give more informations about the error ? I can see the number of errors but I did not find how to get more informations on those errors

Comment: Is there any way for us to test your app ? Maybe someone will try with the specific devices you target

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tmo-dating/id1032349052?mt=8

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.appus.takemeout